# How to implement Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth) to connect to LinkedIn API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, linkedin-api

1. When I try the  [official page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow) or an [other example](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow).
2. I got

   > {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"This application is not allowed to create application tokens"}
3. I added my code below and I am not getting an access token.It shows application is not allowed to create application tokens.

```js
{
  String urlParameters = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id="+linkedInClientId+"&client_secret="+linkedInClientSecret;
  String urlParametersEncoded = "";

  try {
    urlParametersEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(urlParameters, "UTF-8");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("URL Encode error.." + e);
  }

  String url = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?" + urlParametersEncoded;
  String access_token = "null";
  try {
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.linkedin.com");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
      response.append(inputLine);
    }
              in.close();

    //print result
    //System.out.println(response.toString());

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
    access_token = jsonObj.getString("access_token");
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!" + access_token);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("error token.." + e);
  }

  return access_token;
}
```

Comment: Can you add some relevant code, to let people see what you are trying to acheive ?

Comment: @StephanHogenboom I added the code

Comment: you are getting error in step2, have you created the application correctly in step 1 correctly?

Comment: @forkdbloke I created the application correctly but 3-legged permission are added by default.I don't know how to create 2 legged permission

Answer (score 0):

**Two-legged flows** - not member specific but needs some kind of approval

All two-legged flows would require partnership/extended access (https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs)

Learn more about LinkedIn Developer Enterprise products to request permission to the Client Credential Flow.

**Three-legged flow** - member specific

Three legged flows does not require any extended access unlike 2 legged flow, it would be better to make use of three-legged flow instead(which is recommended).

Please follow the steps for **three-legged flow** and it is working for me,

Access this in your browser

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=81101e5urkn5nv&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080/auth/callback&state=aRandomString&scope=r_emailaddress

[image]

Comment: Above link are not providing detail explanation.I want to create 2-legged client credential flow.

Comment: But i want to get access token without user interaction

Comment: `All two-legged flows would require partnership/extended access` what do you mean by this? Just adding the app on linkedin, to get your client_id and client_secret I assume?

Comment: did you have any luck getting 2-legged OAuth authentication work for LinkedIn? I have added all the products that I could for my app in the dashboard and I am still unable to get an application token to access any of the standards APIs such as skills API.
I am following this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow?context=linkedin/skills/context